# jQuery $.ajax is not appending a returned HTML from the server

Tags: jquery

I have a very strange problem with that code. The situation is well known - async load a page via `$.ajax()`. But the problem is, I can use that code only 4 times (after edit: 8 times), after that the result from the server is not being appended. What's wrong ?

### Edit

The situation: before the 4th time the returned HTML is being appended, but after the 4th time the same HTML is not being appended.

```
$('a.menu-item').click(function () {
     loadContent($(this).attr('href'));
});

    function loadContent(hash) {
                window.location.hash = hash;

                $.ajax(
                {
                    url: '/MyAction/' + hash.replace('#', ''),
                    type: 'post',
                    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
                    cache : false,
                    success: function (res) {
                                appendData(res);
                            },
                    complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
                        if(xhr.status == '404') {
                            alert('not found');
                        }
                    } 
             });
    }

function appendData(res) {
        $('#myContent').remove();
        $('<div id="myContent" class="inner-container">'+res+'</div>')
        .appendTo('#mainContainer');
    }
```

Comment: what's happens the last time? did you check the request and the response? also do you make debug in the success callback?

Comment: You don't need that `isLoading` flag. jQuery provides Ajax events that can tell you when Ajax is/isn't happening...

Comment: Is the `if`-branch entered? Set a break-point and check... (or put a `console.log()` inside it, if you don't know how to debug)

Comment: Jorge: in the last time, I can see the returned HTML via firebug, but the `appendData` function is not being fired. The HTML response from the server is the same

Comment: the HTML-responses are different all the time or not? could you add  console.log(xhr.status); in complete method  - what does it show in each case?

Comment: shershen: all the time the `xhr.status` is 200

Comment: @tony: do you mean that `success` callback is not getting executed or only `appendData`? I don't see how `appendData` would not get called unless you omitted some code.

Comment: @Nikola Radosavljević: I didn't ommit any code. Only appendData function is not being executed. If the loaded HTML was different each time I'd suggest that the HTML parsing fails. But, the same HTML sometimes is being appended and sometimes not as I've mentioned before

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `isLoading` flag. It's not defined, nor is it needed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, I've figured it out. I've noticed, that sometimes firebug executes the other function, which name was the same: `loadContent` but it's arguments were different. After renaming that function the problem's gone. Thanks for your help !